# The number of days between two consecutive events

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I'm trying to generate a variable `diff` to denote the number of days between two consecutive events.

```
library(outbreaks)
df <- measles_hagelloch_1861[order(measles_hagelloch_1861$date_of_prodrome), ] 
library(lubridate)
library(plyr)

# First date
firs_date <- min(df$date_of_prodrome)

# Commulative number of days
df$cum_number_day <- difftime(df$date_of_prodrome, firs_date, units = 'days')
head(df$cum_number_day)

# The number of days between two consecutive events
df$diff <- difftime(lag(df$date_of_prodrome, 1), df$date_of_prodrome, units = "days" )
head(df$diff)
```

and result

```
Time differences in days
[1]  0  2  8  8  9 12
Time differences in days
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Could you explain why I get the desired result with the first command but just get `0 0 0` for the second one?

Comment: What's wrong with my question that it gets downvoted?

Comment: Not my downvote but I guess the downvote is because you have not provided a reproducible example. It is usually easy to help if you provide an example that we can work on. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: I'm sorry @RonakShah, but I think that my code is sef-contained and reproducible. I mean I included the necessary packages and explanation for each line of code.

Comment: Ohh..I see. At least I did not realize that the data was from `outbreaks` package. Upvoted +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your code is using `stats::lag` instead of `dplyr::lag`. See the difference :

```
df$diff <- difftime(stats::lag(df$date_of_prodrome, 1),df$date_of_prodrome, units = "days" )
head(df$diff)

#Time differences in days
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0

df$diff <- difftime(dplyr::lag(df$date_of_prodrome, 1), df$date_of_prodrome, units = "days" )
head(df$diff)

#Time differences in days
#[1] NA -2 -6  0 -1 -3
```